# Redis connect single instance slave (slave of) to cluster or sentinel

Tags: redis, cluster-computing, sentinel

When running a single instance redis, I can use "slave of" to create a (or as many I like) readonly replica of this one redis node.

When using redis cluster, I split my Data into Partitons (Masters) and can create a slave for each partition.

Is it possible to treat this cluster as a single instance and connect a "slave of" Slave to this cluster which will hold a replica of all Data in the cluster and not just the partition of the connected node?

If not possible with redis cluster, is this might a working solution when using sentinel?

Our current Problem:
We are using the "slave of" feature together with keepalived to failover our redis instance on an outage of the master.

But we have lots of "slave of" slaves connected to the virtual IP of the failover setup, to deliver cached data.
Now everytime the system fails over (for maintenance reasons e.g.) all connected slaves have a timout for up to 30 seconds, when they have to resync their data with the new master.

We allready played with all possible redis config parameters but can't get this syncing time to be shorter (e.g. by relying on the replication-backlog, which isn't available on the new master after the failover).

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

a very good doc here : http://redis.io/presentation/Redis_Cluster.pdf and here http://fr.slideshare.net/NoSQLmatters/no-sql-matters-bcn-2014 (slide #9) or better https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/09/redis-clustering.html

If you want "slave" in Redis cluster mode, you need use replication of all nodes.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just read this article:

https://seanmcgary.com/posts/how-to-build-a-fault-tolerant-redis-cluster-with-sentinel

The author used a single master with Redis Cluster, with 2 slaves per master, instead of one, and he let Redis Sentinel take care of the election of a slave to a master when the master is down.

You could play with this setup to see if the election of Master occurs quickly. While it's happening, clients would be served by a slave and  should experience no downtime.